# Access a value in the redux store in the App.js

Tags: react-admin

I'm using react-admin. I would need to be able to access a value in the redux store in the App.js file. Based on this value, I pass different props to the Resources components included in Admin.

If I access the store in a classic way I get an error like this:
could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a

This is normal because the App is not wrapped by the provider. But do I have a way to do it by leaning on another component? Or some other way?

Thank you

```
const App = () => {

  const theme = useSelector(state => state.theme);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadReCaptcha();
    console.log('theme', theme);    
  }, []);

  return (
    <Admin
      title="Atena"
      dataProvider={dataProvider}
      customReducers={{ theme: themeReducer }}

      ....
```

Comment: You're talking about the react-admin redux store? The store won't be initialized before the Admin component is mounted so there will be no information to grab. You can use the initialValue prop to pass initial data into the admin component.

Maybe you can give an example of what you're trying to do and we could help you find another way to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JeremyRichardson

I try to explain myself better.

With an initial default value that's fine. But I need it then to be dynamic if it is changed.

What I need to do is access the value of a state in redux managed by a custom reducer that I set in Admin. As the theme in the example.

A component wrapped by admin, later, will modify the state of the theme, through the themeReducer invoked with useSelector.

At this point I need Admin to be triggered by updating the theme value.